# iOS App shows "Request time out" error when there is network

Tags: ios, objective-c, httprequest, nsurlsession

- Intermittently my app throws "Request time out" errors when making requests to my server.
- Sometimes it happens continuously that only quitting and relaunching the app solves it.
- We have a proxy server to track the errors for my requests to the server. **All calls that time to the proxy server to track the errors are successful**.
- That concludes it is not a network issue, or multiple simultaneous requests from the app, because requests are reaching the Proxy server.
- Increasing the timeOut interval does not solve the issue.
- The apis and params sent for the failed requests are all right, the same as when we get success response.

Code Block:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:</* my urlString> */];
    NSData *postData = // My data
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

 // Creating URLRequest
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:120];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// Creating NSURLSession and sending the request

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    configuration.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;
    configuration.URLCache = nil;
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];  
 NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
// Response handling
}
```

Can somebody help? Please suggest if anything has to be checked from the server side as well.

Comment: Please include some of the Obj-C network code in the question.

Comment: Have added the code as asked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add **NSAppTransportSecurity** key to your project's info.plist file.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Are you using Alamofire or something? If yes, then there is a property to set **Timeout** callback.

Comment: Not using Alamofire. Using NSURLSession as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`Request Time Out` simply means that request which sent by your app could not reach back to your app with a response in a given time interval there could be hundred reasons behind this I will suggest you do the following troubleshooting:

- Remove the proxy server in between of your app and the server
- Increase request timeout interval in your app
- Try sending the request with some http client like [postman](https://www.postman.com)

Comment: - Not using the proxy server in between. Another request to the proxy server to track the error is successful, calls to the server fails with request time out. Increasing the request time out does not fix the issue as already mentioned. Sending from postman will be successful as it is not a problem with the request. The same request will work from the app as well once relaunched the app.

Comment: Incase if it is working when you launch the app for second time means there isn't any problem with your code or the app settings this might be an issue of internet availability when you launch app for the first time, make sure internet is working fine when app is in debug mode.